# Convert SQL to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I convert following SQL query to ActiveRecord Query in order to mitigate SQL injection?

```
jacket_colors ||= [2,21,25,20]
jacket_types = JacketType.find_by_sql(<<-SQL)
  SELECT j2.*, t1.no_count
   FROM jeans j2
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT
     j1.jean_id AS jean_id,
     COUNT(j1.id) AS no_count
     FROM tracks t
     INNER JOIN jacket_types j1 ON j1.track_id = t.id
     INNER JOIN jeans j2 ON j2.id = j1.jean_id
     WHERE t.status = 0
       AND j1.status IN (#{jacket_colors})
       AND t.type != 'TrekkingTrack'
     GROUP BY j1.jean_id
     HAVING COUNT(j1.id) > 0
   ) t1 ON t1.jean_id = j2.id
 SQL
```

**jacket_types** varies with user input.

I tried the following but this doesn't work and produces incorrect SQL.

```
jacket_colors ||= [2,21,25,20]

Jean.joins(:jacket_types, :track)
.select('jeans.jacket_types_id AS jacket_types_id, COUNT(jeans.id) AS no_count').
where('jeans.status IN (?) AND tracks.status = ? AND tracks.type != ?', jacket_colors, 0, 'TrekkingTrack')
.group('jeans.jacket_types_id')
.having('COUNT(jeans.id) > ?', 0)
.select('jacket_types.*, tracks.no_count').explain
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I've but I am facing problems converting `j1.status IN (#{jacket_types})` to `'j1.status IN (?)', jacket_types` form.

Comment: @zoras please at least show us what you've already tried, even if it isn't quite finished, we will help you.

Comment: @zoras has you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4208556/456814)?

Comment: @Cupcake just tried it however it doesn't work with the string interpolation as it is within the inner join itself.

Comment: @zoras please edit your question to add additional code, adding it to a comment makes it hard to read.

Comment: @Cupcake added attempted incorrect code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try it, I think it will work.

Rails Query version:

```
jacket_colors ||= [2,21,25,20]

Jean.joins(:jacket_types => :track)
 .where('jeans.status IN (?) AND tracks.status = ? AND tracks.type != ?',
 jacket_colors, 0, 'TrekkingTrack').group('jeans.jacket_types_id')
.select('jacket_types.column1, jacket_types.column2, ....., 
 count(jacket_types) no_count').having("no_count > 0")
```

of

```
jacket_colors ||= [2,21,25,20]
jacket_types = JacketType.find_by_sql(<<-SQL)
  SELECT j2.*, t1.no_count
  FROM jeans j2
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
      j1.jean_id AS jean_id,
      COUNT(j1.id) AS no_count
      FROM tracks t
        INNER JOIN jacket_types j1 ON j1.track_id = t.id
        INNER JOIN jeans j2 ON j2.id = j1.jean_id
        WHERE t.status = 0
        AND j1.status IN (#{jacket_colors})
        AND t.type != 'TrekkingTrack'
        GROUP BY j1.jean_id
        HAVING COUNT(j1.id) > 0
   ) t1 ON t1.jean_id = j2.id
 SQL
```